# imagepng() of gd library not working in php

Tags: php, gd

```
<?php
ob_start();
if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
    echo "PHP GD library is installed on your web server";
} else {
    echo "PHP GD library is NOT installed on your web server";
}


ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$ImagesDirectory     = '/var/www/html/images1/images2/';
$DestImagesDirectory = '/var/www/html/images1/images3/';
$NewImageWidth       = 21;
$NewImageHeight      = 21;
$Quality             = 80;
$ext1                = "png";
if ($dir = opendir($ImagesDirectory)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {

        $imagePath       = $ImagesDirectory . $file;
        $destPath        = $DestImagesDirectory . $file;
        $checkValidImage = @getimagesize($imagePath);

        if (file_exists($imagePath) && $checkValidImage) {

            if (resizeImage($imagePath, $destPath, $NewImageWidth, $NewImageHeight, $ext1)) {
                echo $file . ' resize Success!<br />';


            } else {
                echo $file . ' resize Failed!<br />';
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}

function resizeImage($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext)
{

    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
    $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
    if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
        $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
    } else {
        $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
    }
    $img = "";

    $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    echo $img;
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    echo $tci;
    imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    if (imagepng($tci, $newcopy, 80)) {
        echo "tested";

    } else {
        echo "not tested";
    }

}

?>
```

I want  to resize  the png images to png images .According  to my code imagepng() function is not working .Always execute the else condition and print not tested.I have checked that gd library is installed .

Comment: Do you `ob_end_clean()` or similar somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Value of compression quality must between 0 and 9 for png.
I think, it will fix the issue.